# Yii2 swiftmailer - foreach mail sending (batch)

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I need to send batch emails, and every mail have unique message. I am trying foreach loop, but I keep getting **Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 66 bytes)** error. 
Is it possible to perform foreach with swiftmailer, or there is some other way (message contains unique token). Code:

```
$users = Users::find()->where(['email' => $emails])->all();

        foreach($users as $user):


                $user->scenario = 'saveToken';

                $token = hash('sha256',microtime() . Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(32));

                $user->token = $token;

                $user->save();

               Email::oldUsers($user->email, $token);


        endforeach;
```

Sending emails:

```
static function oldUsers($userEmail, $token)
    {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose('_oldUsers', ['token' => $token])
            ->setFrom('no-reply@sketchlist.com')
            ->setTo($userEmail)
            ->setBcc(['vlad@sketchlist.com'])
            ->setSubject('Sketchlist Account Activation')
            ->send();
    }
```

Comment: There are a few things you might be doing to produce this error. 

maybe you are exhausting the memory when creating a to large array of recipients. ? Try to get a single email at a time instead of all the emails in 1 try?

Answer (score 0):

Try these in the function you are performing email.

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
```

If this doesn't help then follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187836/2559712)

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you how I would code this. Just in case it helps someone, as this is an old, unanswered, question.

There really isn't a need to use scenarios for this. It is such a simple task. Also, you don't need to hash on top of `generateRandomString()`. If your wanting to create a unique and random `token`, just use `generateRandomKey()` which defaults to 32 in length as well.

Also, use `save(false)` or `update(false)`. The false turns validation off. When you are not using user input, and you yourself are programmatically entering the data based off controlled values, you should disable validation rules. I prefer to use `update` when I am doing this, as it makes more sense when we are working with an already existing model.

In your User IdentityInterface (common\models\User.php in advanced):

```
public function generateToken()
{
    $this->token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

public function getToken()
{
    return $this->token;
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $emails = ['email@example.com', 'email2@example.com', 'email3@example.com'];
    $users = Users::find()->where(['email' => $emails])->all();

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $user->generateToken();

        if ( $user->update(false) )
        {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('_oldUsers', ['token' => $user->getToken()])
                ->setFrom(['no-reply@sketchlist.com' => 'Your Name'])
                ->setTo($user->email)
                ->setBcc(['vlad@sketchlist.com'])
                ->setSubject('Sketchlist Account Activation')
                ->send();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have memory problems in foreach loop you should try to retrieve data in batches like this retrieve for example 10 records in each iteration

```
foreach (Users::find()->where(['email' => $emails])->each(10) as $user) {

}
```