# Failed jobs handling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I'm using Laravel Horizon which has a Failed Jobs section which used to work fine. Until I added the Sentry notification for failed jobs, in Job's Class.

```
/**
 * Handle a job failure.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function failed(\Exception $exception)
{
    if ( app()->bound('sentry') ) {
        app('sentry')->captureException($exception);
    }
}
```

Now, when visiting the Failed Jobs tab in Horizon - it results in fatal error with memory exceeded. How can I make both Horizon and this sentry notification work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create command to clean up older records of `failed_jobs` table.

```
public function handle()
{
    // mention days count as required
    DB::table('failed_jobs')->where('failed_at', '<', now()->subDays(10))->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start and increasing memory, following the "[How to increase the PHP memory_limit for better performance?](https://www.atatus.com/blog/the-php-memory_limit-what-you-need-to-know-about-increasing-it/)" article from [Vaishnavi Parameswaran](https://twitter.com/VaishnaviParam2).

But check also if the memory limitation actually comes from the OS instead of PHP, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17187836/6309).

The 2018 [`laravel/horizon` issues 375](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/375#issuecomment-423841619) also referenced [`laravel/horizon/src/Listeners/MonitorMasterSupervisorMemory.php`](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/5.x/src/Listeners/MonitorMasterSupervisorMemory.php#L20) as a possible cause.

```php
        if ($master->memoryUsage() > config('horizon.memory_limit', 64)) {
            $master->terminate(12);
```

So double-check your [`laravel/horizon/config/horizon.php`](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/b822d758035481987066d9425f69649b41f37330/config/horizon.php#L158-L169) setting.

---

As in [`laravel/horizon` issue 748](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/748), check your sentry.io errors for a line similar to:

```
Invoked Artisan command: horizon:work -- input | 'horizon:work' redis --delay=0 --memory=128 --queue=default --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=2 --supervisor='b396ac2bb269-E0QY:supervisor-1'
```

Again, you will see a `--memory` argument which could have an impact here.